# Signed angle in phase() in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, orientation, angle

The manual in OpenCV for the phase() (and so cartToPolar()) function says that it returns the rotation angle for x- and y-gradients in the range 0-360 degrees (with TRUE parameter) using the equation

```
atan2(y(i),x(i)) * 180/pi
```

However, applying manually for some random x/y-gradients values and using the same above equation, I get results with signed values

Example:

Gx=46 and Gy=-22

atan2(-22/46)*180/3.14 = -25.572929

while the results using phase() = 334.437073

Yeah they are the same angle, yet I'd like to retain the sign (if possible) using functions and without using manual iterations. Is there a function (or a trick) to do that in OpenCV? Thank you :)

Comment: `double angle = atan2(Gy,Gx)*180.0/pi; if (Gy < 0) angle = 360.0 - angle;`

Comment: Hi there, sorry if I didn't explain it well because your answer is confusing for me. It removes the sign while I want to keep it using a built-in opencv functions (if any).

Comment: Sorry, didnt understand the question then. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I couldn't find a function in OpenCV that does the trick.
However, the only thing left for me is using a loop and applying 

`if (angle>180) {
    angle = angle-360;
}`

Answer (score 0):

When you are iterating through every pixel,
calculate angle with the formula above, but use **float/double** values, and store them to corresponding cv::Mat *varName*:

```html
for y.rows
 for x.cols
   //calculate angle ( formula from above)
   // Hint: Use same access to G_x and G_y gradients
   *varname*.at<float>(y,x) = angle;
 end for
end for
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled over the same problem with OpenCV 3.4 and wondered why the returned angles are different from the angles obtained with the standard C function *atan2()*.

It turned out that the documentation of the *phase()* function in the OpenCV docs is misleading because the angle is *not* computed with the standard *atan2()* function, but with OpenCV's own implementation *fastAtan2()*, which returns an angle range in degrees between 0° and 360°, and not between -π and π, as is specified by the C standard for *atan2*.